# Access to Windows 10 share works from Windows 10 but not from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-10, smb

I have a domain joined Windows 10 Enterprise (upgraded from Win 8.1) with a local user "x". I create a share and give "x" some rights on the share, Read or whatever. Folder rights are covered by "Everyone" but I can also give "x" explicit access, doesn't matter.

Now I do

```
net use \\mycomputer\share password /user:mycomputer\x
```

This works fine on my local machine and on two other Windows 10 computers, but not from a variety of Windows 8.1 machines (including freshly installed ones). The error shown is "Access denied".

When I look at the Windows security event log on the share machine I see a successful authentication for user "x", followed by a logon for that user and (only in case of "access denied") an immediate logoff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it with Wireshark by comparing a successful auth request with an unsuccessful one. The unsuccessful was suspiciously 9 bytes longer...

After digging into the deepest recesses of the NTLMv2 response I found the difference. I didn't use a FQDN on the computer name and while the (working) Win10 request set the `Target Name` attribute to plain `cifs/mycomputername`, the Win8.1 request set it to `cifs/mycomputername.x.y.com` where `x.y.com` was the primary DNS suffix.

So the solution was to use the FQDN on the username like

```
net use \\mycomputer\share password /user:mycomputer.mydomain.com\x
```